How to get the last value in json array
How can I get the last value in a json array.
row =
 {'title': 'Consolidated form', 'question_type': 'year_of_birth_question', 'tags': 'test-form', 'slug': 'test-form', 'version': 'v1.01', 'locale': 'en', 'high_result_page': 'assessment-result-high', 'high_inflection': '50', 'medium_result_page': '0', 'medium_inflection': 'assessment-result-moderate', 'low_result_page': '30', 'skip_threshold': 'assessment-result-low', 'skip_high_result_page': '1', 'generic_error': 'skip-result-page', 'question': 'Oops, something strange happened. Please try again. If this keeps happening, contact Engineering.', 'explainer': 'What year were you born in', 'error': '', 'min': '', 'max': '', 'answers': '', 'scores': '', 'answer_semantic_ids': '', 'question_semantic_id': '', 'None': ['yob-question']}

My application sometimes fails to retrieve the last key element as seen above so I'd like to be able to get the last value (yob-question) and let the user know that there was no key value retrieved for yob-question.
I'm not looking for a hard coded solution because the last element in the list may not always be yob-question.
Thanks
I tried to print it this way:
print(row[-1]) but that returns a key error.

Your row is not a json array, it's an object (consists of unordered key-value pairs). However, key 'None' of that object refers to array ['yob-question'], first and last element of which is string 'yob-question'. So I guess here, you want row['None'][-1].

That's not valid JSON. JSON only uses double quotes around strings, not single quotes. It's a Python dictionary that contains a list in one of the values.

It took me a minute to clean up your code, and I'm not entirely sure what you're looking for, but I think this might work, or at least get you headed in the correct direction:
import json

data = {
'title': 'Consolidated form',
'question_type': 'year_of_birth_question',
'tags': 'test-form',
'slug': 'test-form',
'version': 'v1.01',
'locale': 'en',
'high_result_page': 'assessment-result-high',
'high_inflection': '50',
'medium_result_page': '0',
'medium_inflection': 'assessment-result-moderate',
'low_result_page': '30',
'skip_threshold': 'assessment-result-low',
'skip_high_result_page': '1',
'generic_error': 'skip-result-page',
'question': 'Oops, something strange happened. Please try again. If this   keeps happening, contact Engineering.',
'explainer': 'What year were you born in',
'error': '',
'min': '',
'max': '',
'answers': '',
'scores': '',
'answer_semantic_ids': '',
'question_semantic_id': '',
'None': ['yob-question']
}

Check for the value of 'None' key and its content
  if 'None' in data and is instance(data['None'], list) and 'yob-question' in data['None']:
    print("The key 'None' contains 'yob-question'.")
 else:
    print("The key 'None' does not contain 'yob-question'.")

Print Dictionary
 print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
